# How can I fix my logic error for score deduction and the strike through?

Tags: java, oop, jtextpane, decrement, strikethrough

I have been working on the finishing touches for my boggle game for the past couple of days and I have most of the functionality working. Unfortunately there are a few areas that are not working correctly despite the code for said functions being present. No matter how many times I play the game the program fails to notify the user how many words that the computer has found, strike through the randomly selected words, and decrement the player's score based on the matching words.

Boogle UI code:

```
package userInterface;

/**
 *
 * @author Zac
 */

import core.Board;
import core.Die;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.text.AttributeSet;
import javax.swing.text.BadLocationException;
import javax.swing.text.DefaultStyledDocument;
import javax.swing.text.Style;
import javax.swing.text.StyleConstants;


public final class BoggleUi {
    private Board board;
    private JFrame jframe;

    //MenuBar
    private JMenuBar  menubar;
    private JMenu boggle;
    private JMenuItem game;
    private JMenuItem exit;

    //Boggle Panel
    private Board boggleBoard;
    private JPanel bogglePanel;
    private ArrayList dictionaryData;//arraylist for dictionary
    private ArrayList diceButtons;//arratlist for dicebuttons

    ArrayList <String> wordsFoundbyPlayer = new ArrayList();

    ArrayList <String> computersWords = new ArrayList();

    private JButton[][] dieButton;

    //Words Panel
    private JPanel wordsPanel;
    private JTextArea textArea;
    private JScrollPane scrollPane;
    private JLabel timerLabel;
    private JButton Shakedice;

    //InputPanel
    private JPanel inputPanel;
    private JLabel currentWord; 
    private JButton submitWord;
    private JLabel currentScore;
    int score = 0;

    //Timer
    private int seconds = 59;
    private int minutes = 2;
    Timer timeCounter;

    //Current Word
    String currentLetter = "";
    String Letters = "";
    int rows;
    int cols;
    private boolean[][] diceButtonCheck;

    //style variables

    JTextPane wordsArea;

    BoggleStyleDoc document;

    ArrayList <String> computerWords = new ArrayList();

    boolean Randomwords[];

    public BoggleUi(Board inBoard, ArrayList readDictionary)
    {
        diceButtons = new ArrayList();
        board = inBoard;
        System.out.println(readDictionary.size());
        dictionaryData = readDictionary;
        initComponents();


    }

    public void initComponents() {

        jframe = new JFrame("Boggle");
        jframe.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        jframe.setSize(600, 500);
        jframe.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(600 , 500));

         menubar = new JMenuBar();

         document = new BoggleStyleDoc();

        //Menu
        createMenu();

        //Panels
        BogglePanel();
        WordPanel();
        InputPanel();

        //Adds Panels to Layout Manager(BorderLayout)
        jframe.setJMenuBar( menubar);
        jframe.add(bogglePanel, BorderLayout.WEST);
        jframe.add(wordsPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        jframe.add(inputPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        jframe.setVisible(true);

        timeCounter= new Timer(1000, new TimeListener());
    }

    //Menu Bar
    private void createMenu(){
         menubar = new JMenuBar();
        boggle = new JMenu("Boggle");

        game = new JMenuItem("New Game");
        game.addActionListener(new GameListener());

        exit = new JMenuItem("Exit");
        exit.addActionListener(new ExitListener());

        boggle.add(game);
        boggle.add(exit);

         menubar.add(boggle);
    }

    //Boggle Panel
    private void BogglePanel(){
        bogglePanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(4, 4));
        bogglePanel.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(400, 400));
        bogglePanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 400));
        bogglePanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Boggle Board"));

        ArrayList<Die> dice = board.shakeDice();//array list for dice

        dieButton = new JButton[4][4];
        diceButtonCheck= new boolean[4][4];
        //dieButton.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 48));
        for(int i=0; i<4; i++){//nested loop for 2d array
            for(int j=0; j<4; j++){     
                String dieLetter = dice.get(4*i +j).getLetter();
                dieButton[i][j] = new JButton(dieLetter);
                dieButton[i][j].setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 40));
                bogglePanel.add(dieButton[i][j]);
                dieButton[i][j].addActionListener(new DiceListener());
                dieButton[i][j].setEnabled(false);
                diceButtonCheck[i][j] = false;
            }
        }
    }

    //Word Panel
    private void WordPanel(){
        wordsPanel = new JPanel();
        wordsPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(wordsPanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        wordsPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Enter Words Found"));

        JPanel noWrapPanel = new JPanel();//new Jpanel for no wrap panel

        wordsArea = new JTextPane();
        //noWrapPanel.add(wordsArea);//adds the wordsarea to the no wrap panel
        wordsArea.setEnabled(false);
        scrollPane = new JScrollPane(wordsArea);
        scrollPane.add(noWrapPanel);//adds no wrap panel to scroll pane
        scrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(180, 330));
        scrollPane.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
        scrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);

        timerLabel = new JLabel("3:00");
        timerLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        timerLabel.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 45));
        timerLabel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(175, 75));
        timerLabel.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(175, 75));
        timerLabel.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(175, 75));
        timerLabel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Time Left"));


        Shakedice = new JButton("Shake Dice");
        Shakedice.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(175, 50));
        Shakedice.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(175, 50));
        Shakedice.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(175, 50));
        Shakedice.addActionListener(new ShakeListener());
        Shakedice.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 20));
        Shakedice.setEnabled(true);

        wordsPanel.add(scrollPane);
        wordsPanel.add(timerLabel);
        wordsPanel.add(Shakedice);
    }

    //Input Panel
    private void InputPanel(){

        //setup input panel

        inputPanel = new JPanel();
        inputPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        inputPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Current Word"));

        currentWord = new JLabel();
        currentWord.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(240, 50));
        currentWord.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(240, 50));
        currentWord.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(240, 50));
        currentWord.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Current Word"));

        //set up submit word button

        submitWord = new JButton("Submit Word");
        submitWord.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(175, 50));
        submitWord.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(175, 50));
        submitWord.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(175, 50));
        submitWord.addActionListener(new WordListener());
        submitWord.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 20));
        submitWord.setEnabled(false);

        //setup score

        currentScore = new JLabel();
        currentScore.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 50));
        currentScore.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(100, 50));
        currentScore.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(100, 50));
        currentScore.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Score"));

        //adds current word, submit word and current score to the input panel

        inputPanel.add(currentWord);
        inputPanel.add(submitWord);
        inputPanel.add(currentScore);      
    }

    //Exit's the program
    private class ExitListener implements ActionListener{
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            int response = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Confirm to exit Boggle?", 
                    "Exit?", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);

            if (response == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION)
                System.exit(0); 
        }   
    }

    //New Game( resets JTextArea, time to 3:00 on JLabel, and reenables shake dice button)
    private class GameListener implements ActionListener{
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            wordsArea.setText("");
            Shakedice.setEnabled(true);
            submitWord.setEnabled(false);
            wordsFoundbyPlayer.clear();
            timerLabel.setText("3:00");
            minutes=2;
            seconds = 59;
            timeCounter.stop();

            //nested loop to disable the die button

            for(int i = 0; i<4; i++ ){
                for(int j = 0; j<4; j++){
                    dieButton[i][j].setEnabled(false);
                    diceButtonCheck[i][j] = false;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    //Shakes Dice( shakes dice, starts the timer,
    private class ShakeListener implements ActionListener{
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){

            ArrayList<Die> dice = board.shakeDice();

            bogglePanel.removeAll();
            bogglePanel.revalidate();

            Shakedice.setEnabled(false);
            submitWord.setEnabled(true);
            timeCounter.start();
            score = 0;
            currentScore.setText(""+ score);
            currentLetter = "";
            currentWord.setText(currentLetter);

            Collections.shuffle(dice);
            dieButton = new JButton[4][4];
            diceButtonCheck= new boolean[4][4];

            for(int i=0; i<4; i++){
                for(int j=0; j<4; j++){
                    String dieLetter = dice.get(4*i +j).getLetter();
                    dieButton[i][j] = new JButton(dieLetter);
                    dieButton[i][j].setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 40));
                    bogglePanel.add(dieButton[i][j]);
                    dieButton[i][j].addActionListener(new DiceListener()); 
                    dieButton[i][j].setEnabled(true);
                    diceButtonCheck[i][j] = false;
                }
            }


        }
    }

    //word listener

    private class WordListener implements ActionListener{
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            int flag = 0; //flag varible



            boolean validateWord = false;// variable to validate a word

                for(int n = 0; n < wordsFoundbyPlayer.size(); n++){

            if(wordsFoundbyPlayer.get(n).compareTo(currentLetter) == 0){

                validateWord = true;



            }

            }

        wordsArea.setDocument(document);

         if(validateWord == false){

                wordsFoundbyPlayer.add(currentLetter);

                for(int i=0; i< dictionaryData.size(); i++){

                if(currentLetter.equalsIgnoreCase(dictionaryData.get(i).toString())){

                    flag = 1;
                    int wordLength = currentLetter.length();
                    if(wordLength <= 2){
                        try {
                            document.insertString(0,"Word is too short!\n",null);

                            //internal try catch block
                        } catch (BadLocationException ex) {
                            Logger.getLogger(BoggleUi.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                        }

                        }
                    else if(wordLength <= 4){
                        try {
                            score += 1;
                            document.insertString(0,currentLetter+"\n",null);
                        } catch (BadLocationException ex) {
                            Logger.getLogger(BoggleUi.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                        }
                        }
                    else if(wordLength == 5){
                        try {
                            score += 2;
                            document.insertString(0,currentLetter+"\n",null);
                        } catch (BadLocationException ex) {
                            Logger.getLogger(BoggleUi.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                        }
                        }
                    else if(wordLength == 6){
                        try {
                            score += 3;
                            document.insertString(0,currentLetter+"\n",null);
                        } catch (BadLocationException ex) {
                            Logger.getLogger(BoggleUi.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                        }
                        }
                    else if(wordLength == 7){
                        try {
                            score += 5;
                            document.insertString(0,currentLetter+"\n",null);
                        } catch (BadLocationException ex) {
                            Logger.getLogger(BoggleUi.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                        }
                        }
                    else if(wordLength >= 8){
                        try {
                            score += 11;
                            document.insertString(0,currentLetter+"\n",null);
                        } catch (BadLocationException ex) {
                            Logger.getLogger(BoggleUi.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                        }
                        }
                    break;
                }
            }

            //check if the word entered is vaild or not

            if(flag == 0){

                //surrounding try catch statement
                    try { 
                        document.insertString(0,"Word is invalid!\n", null);
                    } catch (BadLocationException ex) {
                        Logger.getLogger(BoggleUi.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                    }



            }

            //for loop to caluate score based on length

            for(int i = 0; i<4; i++ ){
                for(int j = 0; j<4; j++){
                    dieButton[i][j].setEnabled(true);
                    diceButtonCheck[i][j] = false;
                }
            }

            }

         if(validateWord == true){

               JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Word is a repeat!");

            }



            currentLetter = "";
            currentWord.setText(currentLetter);
            currentScore.setText(""+score);
    }

    }
    //dice listener

private class DiceListener implements ActionListener{
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            JButton b;

            Letters = e.getActionCommand();
            b = (JButton)e.getSource();
            currentLetter += Letters;
            currentWord.setText(currentLetter);

            for(int i = 0; i<4; i++ ){//nested loop for validation
                for(int j = 0; j<4; j++){
                    dieButton[i][j].setEnabled(false);
                    if(b == dieButton[i][j]){ 
                        rows = i;
                        cols = j;
                        diceButtonCheck[i][j] = true;
                    }
                }
            }
            for(int i = rows -1; i <= rows +1; i++ ){//nested loop to enable or disable the die button
                for(int j = cols -1; j <= cols +1; j++ ){
                    if( i>=0 && i<4 && j>=0 && j<4) {
                        dieButton[i][j].setEnabled(true);
                    if(diceButtonCheck[i][j])
                        dieButton[i][j].setEnabled(false);
                    }
                }
            }

        }



    }


//Actionlistener for the timer

private class TimeListener implements ActionListener{
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            String s = String.format(" "+minutes+ ":" + "%02d", seconds);//concatenate minutes and seconds



            timerLabel.setText(s);
            seconds -=1;
            if(seconds < 0){
                seconds=59;
                if(minutes == 0){
                    timeCounter.stop();
                    submitWord.setEnabled(false);//sets button to false
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Game Over");//option pane for game over

                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The Computer will now compare its words to yours");

                    for(int i = 0; i<4; i++ ){
                        for(int j = 0; j<4; j++){
                            dieButton[i][j].setEnabled(false);
                            diceButtonCheck[i][j] = false;
                        }
                    }
                    return;
                }
                minutes--;
            }
        }
}
            //method for random word selection
        private void randomWordselect(){

            Random randomWord = new Random();

            int randWord = randomWord.nextInt(wordsFoundbyPlayer.size());

            if(Randomwords[randWord] != true){

                Randomwords[randWord] = true;

            }

            else{

                randomWordselect();



            }

        }

            //method for comparing the computer's words against the player's

            private void ComputerCompare(){


               Random rand = new Random();

               int numAIWords = rand.nextInt(wordsFoundbyPlayer.size());

               Randomwords = new boolean[wordsFoundbyPlayer.size()];

               for(int j = 0; j < numAIWords; j++){


                   randomWordselect();

               }
                //for loop to set up strike through

                for(int i = 0; i < wordsFoundbyPlayer.size(); i++ ){



                    StyleConstants.setStrikeThrough(document.getterStyle(), true);

                    wordsArea.setDocument(document);





                }
                //for loop with the switch case statement to decrement the player's score
                for(int n = 0; n < wordsFoundbyPlayer.size(); n++){

                    if(Randomwords[n] == true){

                        System.out.println( "Word" + n + "of the Player's words were found");

                        StyleConstants.setStrikeThrough(document.getterStyle(), true);

                        wordsArea.setDocument(document);

                      int deduction = wordsFoundbyPlayer.get(n).length();

                    switch(deduction){

                                case 0: 
                                case 1: 
                                case 2: 

                                score -=0;

                                 break;

                                case 3: 
                                case 4:
                            score -= 1;

                                break;  

                             case 5:   

                            score -= 2;  

                            break;

                             case 6:   

                            score -= 3;  

                            break;

                            case 7:   

                            score -= 5;  

                            break;

                            default:

                            score -= 11;

                             break;
                    }

                    currentScore.setText(String.valueOf(score));

                    System.out.println("Your total score is" + score);

                    }

                else{

                    StyleConstants.setStrikeThrough(document.getterStyle(),false);

                    wordsArea.setDocument(document);

                }  

                 try{//try catch for location

                    document.insertString(document.getLength(),wordsFoundbyPlayer.get(n) + "\n", null) ;

                 }  

                 catch(Exception ex){

                     System.out.println("Bad Location");

                 }
            }


            }



             // external private class for the default styled document  

      private class BoggleStyleDoc extends DefaultStyledDocument{

    private Style primaryStyle;

    public BoggleStyleDoc(){

        super();

        primaryStyle = this.addStyle("primary", null);

    }
        public Style getterStyle() {

            return primaryStyle;
        }   

        @Override

        public void insertString(int offs, String str, AttributeSet a)

            throws BadLocationException{


            super.insertString(offs, str, primaryStyle);

        }

      }

}
```

As you can tell everything should look correct, but I'm still having issues. I believe the error is somewhere within one of the implementations of wordsArea, but I can't pinpoint where I would need to make the fix. Can someone show or tell me how I could possibly resolve the issues?

Comment: What kind of code debugging have you already done?

Comment: I tried to use a print statement or two. They're still within my code. One is to check if the score is deducting and the other is supposed to notify the user that the computer found a specific amount of words that they have found.

Comment: Run your code step-by-step under debugger. I assume that you are using some modern IDE (like Eclipse), aren't you?

Comment: I'm using Netbeans, so I'll give it a try.